# JQuery not running in views

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Some Jquery scripts are not running in the views while others are running.
I want to hide a certain div "#all_lists" and make it appear on click of the "#add_lists" div. The character counter is also not working!
All Help is appreciated.

Here is my view;

```
<%= provide(:title, 'Send Message') %> 
<div class="send_sms_form">

<%= simple_form_for(@message, :html => {:multipart => true}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

<div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :from, placeholder: "Max 11 characters" %>
    <%= f.input :to, :input_html => {:value => params[:to], :id => "to"}, placeholder: "Separate Numbers with Comma", hint: "Include atleast one number in this section" %>

    <div id="add_lists"> <span class="button"> Add List </span></div>

    <div id="all_lists"> <%= f.collection_check_boxes :lists,  @lists, :id, :name, as: :select %></div>
    <%= f.input :message, :as => :text, :input_html => {:cols => 60, :rows => 7, :onkeypress => "if (this.value.length > 160) { return false; }", id: "compose_message"} %>

    <div><span id="char_count">160</span></div>

    <%= f.input :user_id, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => @current_user.id} %>
    <%= f.input :status, :as => :hidden, :input_html => {:value => "Queued"} %>
    <%= f.button :submit, "Send Message" %>
  <% end %>


</div>
```

And here is the message.js with the jQuery to run in the views

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#to').tagsInput({
//        'autocomplete_url': '/contacts/autocomplete_contact_phone_number',
    'defaultText': 'Add a Number',
    'height': '50px',
    'width': '400px',
    'validator': function (value) {
        console.log(value.length, value);
        if (value.substring(0, 3) == "256" || value.substring(0, 3) == "255" || value.substring(0, 3) == "254") {

            if (value.length >= 11) {
                return true;
            }

        }
        return false;
    }
});

$(".listbox").click(function () {
    var numbers_string = $(this).data("numbers");
    numbers = numbers_string.split(",");
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            $('#to').addTag(numbers[i]);
        }
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {

//                if ($('#to').tagExist(numbers[i])) {
                $('#to').removeTag(numbers[i]);
//                }

        }
    }


});

$('#messages_table').dataTable() ({
    sPaginationType: "full_numbers"
});

$('#compose_message').live('keyup keydown', function(e) {
  var maxLen = 160;
  var left = maxLen - $(this).val().length;
  $('#char_count').html(left);
});



$('#all_lists').hide();
$('#add_lists').click( function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#add_lists').toggle();
});
$(document).click( function(){
    $('#all_lists').hide();
});


});
```

The scripts below are not working

```
 $('#compose_message').live('keyup keydown', function(e) {
  var maxLen = 160;
  var left = maxLen - $(this).val().length;
  $('#char_count').html(left);
});



$('#all_lists').hide();

$('#add_lists').click( function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#all_lists').toggle();
});

$(document).click( function(){
    $('#all_lists').hide();
});
```

Comment: Can you verify the message.js file being loaded?

Comment: I have included it above!!

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> Some Jquery scripts are not running in the views while others are
>   running.

It's not clear what you are saying is running and what is not (is all of messages.js code not running? Or just parts of it?), so this may be only a partial solution.

This answer is regarding this statement:

> I want to hide a certain div "#all_lists" and make it appear on click
>   of the "#add_lists" div.

But your code at the bottom is:

```
$('#all_lists').hide();
$('#add_lists').click( function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('#add_lists').toggle();
});
$(document).click( function(){
    $('#all_lists').hide();
});
```

You need to change `$('#add_lists').toggle();` to `$('#all_lists').toggle();`.

Also, if you want the `all_lists` div to be hidden when the page loads, there isn't really any reason to use jquery to hide it - you can just use css and this would guarantee preventing a potential flicker associated with it being hidden via JQuery.